# Change background color in Word for Mac

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

How can I change page background color (using RGB) in Word for Mac?

I tried the “record macro” tool but that was a blank macro.

The macro I use in Word for PC:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.DisplayBackgrounds = True
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(200, 222, 250)
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Solid
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use it on a Mac. Can you use one of the color constants instead? Here is one that works on the PC: `ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = _
    wdThemeColorAccent3` I will try posting one with a constant as well.

Answer (score 0):

### I am not on a Mac, but see if one of the Word color constants meets your needs.

So, I can't tell you why your macro is not working. I'm sorry.

Instead of `ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(200, 222, 250)` try something like `ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor= wdColorLightGreen`. That corresponds to RGB = 204, 255, 204.

Here is a [list of the Word Color Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.WdColor) with the corresponding RGB settings.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that’s not going to work because I’m particular about the color. I just used that RGB as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this won't work on the Mac version because it does not let you access the `Document.Background` object. If you look for it in `View->Object`, it is there but it is hidden.

AIUI if you set the background color on Windows, you can still *see* it on Mac, and *print* it on Mac if you check the relevant option in `Word->Preferences`. You just can't set it or change it.

I can't see any particularly good alternative either. I can't see a way to do this in AppleScript. You could create a page-sized rectangular shape in a header or footer (so that it appears on all pages in a Word section) and specify a fill, but that will behave differently (I.e. it will probably print whatever is set in Preferences, and if your document has multiple sections, you will need to ensure that the shape is in all of them). Or if you saved the document in Word XML format, you could add/modify necessary XML elements there. You'd have to inspect a document created on the windows version to find out exactly what XML you needed. (I cannot see a way to insert this XML using VBA's InsertXML method either).

NB I do not have enough points here to post comments, so if you have any follow-up, look for changes in this Answer (assuming I can change it!)